# How to create a loop that changes the dataname during each loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

This is a sample code that uses a similar data set:

```
library(portfolio)
p <- new("portfolioBasic", instant = as.Date("2004-12-31"), id.var = "symbol",  
         in.var = "price", sides = "long", 
         ret.var = "month.ret", data = dow.jan.2005)
a <- performance(p)@ret
b <- log(1 + a)
sum <- b + sum #the sum variable should accumulate all returns
```

The example above is very similar to the code I'm working on, except that it uses the dow.jan.2005 that's included in the `portfolio` library.

I want to create a loop in R that calculates a certain function `p <- new(... , data = "data20xx")` and this `data20xx` that is used in the function should go from 2007 to 2017.

There are also two other functions that follow `p`. The performance function `performance(p)` calculates a percentage which then needs to be logarithmized and stored in a separate variable `b`. The `sum` variables keeps track of the cumulative log returns.

Here's the description of the `performance` function:

```
   Formal class 'performance' [package "portfolio"] with 6 slots
      ..@ ret           : num -0.366
      ..@ profit        : num 0
      ..@ missing.price : num NA
      ..@ missing.return: int 0
```

If i use `performance(p)@ret` I get a number, but I can't use the logarithm on it.

How can I create this specific loop?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: oh man! I wanna help you but can't. You should provide more information.

Comment: I've updated my initial post with an example

Comment: Are you aware of the simple mathematical fact that there is no defined value for the log of a negative number????

Comment: For the first issue, you can use a list as `data <- list(data2007, ..., data2017)` and either use `lapply` or a loop with `data = data[[i]]`

Comment: @42 Sorry, I missed that part. Now I've added the correct log return formula.

Comment: @DJack could you provide a full example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach is to put your data frames into a list and apply your function to each element of this list using `lapply`.

```
data <- list(data2005, data2006, data2007)

myfun <- function(x){
  p <- new("portfolioBasic", 
           instant = as.Date("2004-12-31"), 
           id.var = "symbol", in.var = "price",
           sides = "long", ret.var = "month.ret", data = x)
  a <- performance(p)@ret
  b <- log(1 + a)
  b
}

output <- lapply(data, myfun)

sum <- do.call("sum", output)
```

#### Sample data

```
library(portfolio)

set.seed(1)

data(dow.jan.2005)

data2007 <- data2006 <- data2005 <- dow.jan.2005
data2006$price <- runif(nrow(dow.jan.2005), 30, 100)
data2007$price <- runif(nrow(dow.jan.2005), 30, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own answer that I came up with after DJack's suggestions (thanks DJack!):

```
mydata <- list(spxdata2007,spxdata2008 etc.)
p <- lapply(mydata, function(x) log(1+performance(new("portfolioBasic", id.var = "symbol", in.var = "inversepe", type = "linear", sides = c("long", "short"), ret.var = "return", data = x))@ret))
exp(Reduce("+",p))-1
```